# How to filter with group by or distinct clause in constricting oracle json_array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, object

**Having simple database structure**

```
PERSON_ID   FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
1             John          Doe
2             John          Doe
3             Peter       Jackson
```

need to construct single row output with JSON ARRAY structure containing unique data filtered by first_name,last_name criteria.

Expected outcome:

```
[{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe"
},
{
    "firstname": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Jackson"
}]
```

Using group by on array level results in two rows

```
SELECT  json_array(   
                    json_object(  key 'firstname' VALUE t.first_name, 
                                  key 'lastname'  VALUE t.last_name)

                 ) RESPONSEJSON

FROM TESTDATA t
GROUP BY t.first_name, t.last_name



    RESPONSEJSON
1   [{"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Jackson"}]
2   [{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery to create distinct objects. Then aggregate them together in the array:

```
create table t (
  person_id int, first_name varchar2(10), last_name varchar2(10)
);

insert into t values (1, 'John', 'Doe' );
insert into t values (2, 'John', 'Doe' );
insert into t values (3, 'Peter', 'Jackson' );
commit;

with jobjs as (
  select  distinct json_object(  
            key 'firstname' VALUE t.first_name, 
            key 'lastname'  VALUE t.last_name
          ) responsejson
  from    t
)
SELECT  json_arrayagg ( responsejson )
FROM    jobjs;

[
  {"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"},
  {"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Jackson"}
]
```

---

There's a bug in 12.2 which gives wrong results when using `distinct` as above. You can get around this with `group by` instead:

```
with jobjs as (
  select  json_object(  
            key 'firstname' VALUE t.first_name, 
            key 'lastname'  VALUE t.last_name
          ) responsejson
  from    t
  group   by t.first_name, t.last_name
)
SELECT  json_arrayagg ( responsejson )
FROM    jobjs;

[
  {"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Jackson"},
  {"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}
]
```

Comment: It is a single query?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, never used WITH SELECT before.  But with your example,  the result is: [{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"},{"firstname":"Peter","lastname":"Jackson"}]

Comment: Which version of Oracle Database are you using?

Comment: There's a 12.2 bug (fixed in 19c) with distinct; you can use group by instead

Comment: 12.2, with group by all goes fine. Thanks Chris